# Que veut dire « fais pas ton p.d. » ?

Tags: expressions, argot, insultes, vulgarité

J'étais avec mon ami chez lui l'autre jour et il m'a invité à manger au restaurant.  Puis je lui ai dit que je ne pouvais pas y aller car je devais manger avec ma copine.  Il a répondu avec « fais pas ton p.d. » (qui a fait rire mon autre ami) mais il a refusé de me dire le sens.

Que veut dire « fais pas ton p.d. » ?

Comment: *canard* aurait été plus approprié dans ce cas précis.

Comment: A noter, l'usage veut, si vraiment on veut employer cette expression, qu'on l'écrive `PD` (plus courant) ou `pédé` (plus rigoriste quant à l'étymologie)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comme dit [Cédric](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4498/1514), ça commence par être une insulte homophobe, qui devient de plus en plus commune, et perd ce trait d'homophobie au passage.

Ça se traduit bien en anglais par :

> Don't be such an asshole.

Si c'est parce que tu vas manger avec ta [copine](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1515/1514), ça n'en est que plus incongru, et je comprends bien que ça fasse marrer ton autre ami.

Comment: Je trouve le sens originel plus proche de *Don't be (such) a sissy*

Comment: Je te crois sur parole, ce n'est certainement pas le registre de langue que je maitrise le mieux, surtout en anglais.

Comment: @RomainVALERI cette remarque auraoit méritée une réponse à part entière

Answer (score 7):

PD est un acronyme utilisé pour désigner (en général de manière insultante) un homme homosexuel. A l'origine il s'agissait du mot *pédéraste*, qui s'est contracté en *pédé* (ou p.d.).

> Pédé est un terme servant à désigner un homosexuel masculin. Cette
>   dénomination est généralement utilisée comme insulte homophobe. Elle
>   peut aussi être usitée au même titre que le mot « putain », dans le
>   langage populaire et grossier, sans être particulièrement empreinte
>   d'intention homophobe. Ainsi il n'est pas rare d'entendre (à titre
>   d'exemple) : « Putain, t'as vu ce match, quel pédé cet arbitre ! ».

source : [wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9d%C3%A9)

Comment: Il y a assurément une base culturelle homophobe dans ce genre d'expression. Cependant, certains homosexuels utilisant eux-mêmes le mot _pédé_, je crois que son sens se tourne définitivement plus vers celui d'expressions toutes aussi charmantes telles que _gonzesse_ [ou encore _tarlouse_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tarlouse).

Answer (score 2):

Il est vrai que l'insulte a perdu beaucoup de sa connotation homophobe, mais je pense que ça reste la base du terme. C'est pourquoi la meilleure traduction est *"faggot"*, voir *"sissy"* comme l'a dit Romain.

Answer (score 0):

Dans ce cas, c'est bien "ne fais pas le con" ou "l'abruti".

La connotation homo est anecdotique. On emploie ces mots pour n'importe quoi.
Il aurait pu dire "ne fais pas l'enc…"